# Mysqli prepare giving error, even though SQL statement is valid?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having some trouble with a SQL transaction using PHP and mySQL. Here is my statement:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO listings (title, price, seller, description, time, featured)
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0);
SELECT @listingid:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO pictures (listid, primarypic)
                VALUES (@listingid, 1);
COMMIT;
```

While this statement works fine when I put it in directly using phpMyAdmin (substituting the ? marks), it seems to fail when I call

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("statement");
```

Replace "statement" with the above statement. The fact that it fails before getting to the bind_param of the $stmt leaves me to believe that it is not a problem with the parameters, but rather the query.

Here is the exact error, if it helps:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO listings (title, price, seller, description, time, featured) ' at line 2

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `mysqli` can handle compound statements like that (especially since there is a separate [`commit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) function).  Instead of `START TRANSACTION;` at the beginning and `COMMIT;` at the end, you'd do `$mysqli->autocommit(false);` before the query and `$mysqli->commit();` when you're done.

Comment: +1 In addition, from [`mysqli_prepare` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php): _"The query must consist of a single SQL statement."_ and _"Note: You should not add a terminating semicolon or \g to the statement."_

Comment: So should I be putting the $mysqli->commit(); after the $stmt->execute(); ?

Comment: @Wiseguy good catch. Not sure how I missed that. Guess I'll have to make a stored procedure then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can only "prepare" a single SQL statement -- you are trying to prepare five SQL statements here.

One way to do what you want is to create a stored procedure.

From [`mysqli_prepare()` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

> Prepares the SQL query, and returns a statement handle to be used for further operations on the statement. The query must consist of a single SQL statement.